# how to write custom query in CakePHP 3.x to retrieve data from joint tables

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

there are 2 tables 
1: user

```
Id | Name |
1    user1
2    user2
3    user3
```

2: InterestLog

```
id | user_id | user_id_Interested_in |
1     1           2
2     1           3
3     2           1
4     2           3
5     3           1
6     3           2
```

Now in cakephp the query to retrieve data and paginate is following

```
$interestLog = $this->paginate($this->interestLog);

$this->set(compact('interestLog'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['interestLog']);
```

The result is being produced by above query is exact mapping of visitLog table. I need to display names instead of Id

i'm trying to product following result.

```
Id |  USER   |      User Interested In |

1     user1           user2
2     user1           user3
3     user2           user1
4     user2           user3
5     user3           user1
6     user3           user2
```

But i have no idea exactly how to write custom query to produce this result. Can you please give me some hint how to do this one. 
I wrotethe following SQL query which is working perfectly but how it can be converted into cakephp query

```
SELECT  il.Id,s.Name , interest.Name FROM users s , users interest , interest_log il
WHERE  s.Id = il.user_id && il.user_id_interested = interest.Id
```

In CAKEPHP 3.x i'm achieving desired result by following way

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

        $result = $conn->execute("SELECT  il.Id,s.Name , visited.Name 
                        FROM users s , users visited , interest_log il
                        WHERE  
                            s.Id = il.user_id 
                            && 
                            il.user_id_interested = visited.Id"
                    );
```

But can you please advise me if there is any better way to write custom query in CAKEPHP 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple if you have followed cake's convention.
Just try to contain user within paginated data:

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ];
$interestLog = $this->paginate($this->interestLog);

$this->set(compact('interestLog'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['interestLog']);
```

Comment: actually i have used "user id" and "user_id_interested" as foreign key in interestLog table refered to user table, and i need to display names from user table against "user id" and "user_id_interested" exist in InterestLog table

Comment: oh i see..may be you need custom query as you wrote in case of user_id_Interested_in..

Comment: yes i did same thing but now if I debug then result is displays correct data but if i try to display then shows null

Comment: If you share your code that you're using to debug and to display, we might be able to help.